# How can I turn one specific audio file on or off with CheckBox or toggle button from one activity to another in android?

Tags: javascript, android, audio

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class Settings_Menu extends Activity {
private MediaPlayer mp;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings_menu);

    TurnSoundOff();
}

private void TurnSoundOff() { 
    final CheckBox TurnSoundOff= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.StartupsoundoffBox);
    TurnSoundOff.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (TurnSoundOff.isChecked()){
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.class, R.raw.soundfile); //errors at .create since I can't use a class
                mp.stop();
            }else{
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.class, R.raw.soundfile);
                mp.start();
            }
        }});
}
```

}

Here is my code, i'm just trying to shutoff or turn on a designated audio file from when the app opens. I have the Checkbox or toggle button in another activity. I'm using media player and some what new to android coding thanks for reading. I setup a settings action from tapping overflow then the settings button to go to activity and I want the audio shutoff or back on in the MainActivity.xml when the check is click from the settings activity. thanks again for reading and help in advance. It errors at .create since I can't use a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this using shared preferences . It is very simple.. Instead of making an activity make a preference screen.. Follow these steps..:-

1) Go to resource folder.
2) make a new folder called 'xml'.
3) In xml folder you created make a xml file called 'prefs.xml'.

in that sdd the following code..:-

```
 <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:key="music"
    android:summary="Tick to listen the music"
    android:title="Intro Music" >
</CheckBoxPreference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

now go to ur activity that plays the song..

```
  ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splash_sound);

    SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean music = getPrefs.getBoolean("music", true);
    if (music == true)
        ourSong.start();

    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
```

this thread is used for the timer of your activity.. if u dnt want any timer delete the thread.. the value in the sleep(****) is the time in miliseconds.

add this function also to stop the song after the activity is changed..

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
    ourSong.release();
}
```

To get the overflow menu :-
1)make a new folder called menu
2)make a xml file.. add the following code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:title="Preferences"
    android:id="@+id/preferences" />
<item android:title="Exit"
    android:id="@+id/exit" />
</menu>
```

In you actvity add the following code..So that prefernece could be called

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater blowUp = getMenuInflater();
    blowUp.inflate(R.menu.cool_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.preferences:
        Intent b = new Intent("com.example.code.PREFS");
                    //instead of 'com.example.code' write your package name 
        startActivity(b);
        break;
    case R.id.exit:
        finish();
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And in the end make a class called Prefs and add the following code..

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

   public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
}

}
```

Finally add the class in the manifest.. code for that..

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.code.Prefs"
        android:label="Preferences" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.code.PREFS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

your action name should be same as u mentioned in the intent in onMenuItemSelected()...
This would do the trick... :) Peace...

Comment: I'm not sure whats going on now, having problem. Is there a video I can watch I had it working but when the button was ticked or unticked sound still played

Comment: Okay now I got it down where should I add the code so preferences can be called which activity?

Comment: dnt forget to tick if u got ur answer.

Comment: I have all code implemented but when I tick to check it still plays the sound when it shouldn't, I have it set as main.xml the file you had me create and its all setup just having a problem with it stopping the sound thanks for your help again.

Comment: i have tested it myself and it is working fine.. but no probs u just give me ur email i will send u the project .. u just need to import it in your eclipse.. :)

Comment: I got it to work thanks I realized it has to be clicked to play the sound thanks! Is there a way to switch this for future preference? Is there a way to have the box checked to turn sound off? currently its check to turn sound on. Thanks again for help!

Comment: In the second code I posted there is a line. If (music==true) change that to if (music == false)..  this may do wht u want..